# Handling ACTION_SEND

Tags: android, contactscontract

I want to handle ACTION_SEND intent. 
So i get an uri of the shared item using this code:

```
Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
if (extras.containsKey(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM))
{
    Uri uri = (Uri) extras.getParcelable(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM);
    ....
```

this uri is something like this:

```
content://com.android.contacts/contacts/as_vcard/0n3B4537432F4531
```

How i can get exact contact from this uri?

I tried this:

```
Cursor cursor = managedQuery(uri, null, null, null, null);
```

and this:

```
Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(uri, null, null, null, null);
```

and got an exception and program termination in both cases.

Please help!

Comment: Please, provide logcat output.

Comment: Thank you for idea about logcat - i just don't know about it before :)
Problem was trivial - READ_CONTACTS permission. Now Cursor is created however it have not _ID field

Comment: The URI you have is for a contact represented as a VCARD not as contact.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove as_vcard in content://com.android.contacts/contacts/as_vcard/0n3B4537432F4531

If it does not work try this.

```
String key= uri.getPathSegments().get(2);
Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(Uri.withAppendedPath(Contacts.CONTENT_LOOKUP_URI, key),
null, null, null, null);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you receive a `content://` URI in an `EXTRA_STREAM` you should be able to query [`OpenableColumns`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/OpenableColumns.html) to get the meta information.

```
String name = null;
String size = null;

Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(uri, new String[] { OpenableColumns.DISPLAY_NAME, OpenableColumns.SIZE }, null, null, null);
if (cursor != null) {
    try {
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            name = cursor.getString(0);
            size = cursor.getString(1);
        }
    } finally {
        cursor.close();
    }
}
```

To get the actual content use [`ContentResolver.openInputStream(Uri)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentResolver.html#openInputStream(android.net.Uri)) and read the stream. Don't forget to close it afterwards.